# PyQt5: How to Get Dimensions of Displayed Widgets

Tags: pyqt5, pyside2, qwidget, dimensions, qlabel

I have PyQt5 QLabels that expand/contract as the QMainWindow size changes.  I want to get the dimensions of the QLabels when the QMainWindow is sized to anything other that its initial dimensions.

The script below creates two QLabels in a QMainWindow.  The QLabels expand but the top QLabel has a fixed height.  The QMainWindow is created with dimensions 400x300 and and displays as screen maximized using `showMaximized()` (in my case, 1920 x 1080).  The script prints the dimensions of the QLabels before and after the QMainWindow displays.  Prior to display, `width()` and `height()` return default QLabel values and after display (screen maximized) `width()` and `height()` return values as if the QMainWindow has physical dimensions of 400x300.  Here is wat is printed:

```
label_1 Size Before Expanding:  100 100
label_2 Size Before Expanding:  100 30
label_1 Size After Expanding:  378 100
label_2 Size After Expanding:  378 171
```

How can I get the true dimensions for the QLabels when the QMainWindow is maximized? I'm running in a Windows environment.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QSizePolicy, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):  
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)        
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 300)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        
        self.label_1 = QLabel(self)
        self.label_1.setStyleSheet('background-color: green')
        self.label_1.setFixedHeight(100)
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.label_1.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label_1)
        
        self.label_2 = QLabel(self)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet('background-color: red')
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.label_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        
        print('label_1 Size Before Expanding: ', self.label_1.width(), self.label_1.height())
        print('label_2 Size Before Expanding: ', self.label_2.width(), self.label_2.height())
        self.showMaximized()
        print('label_1 Size After Expanding: ', self.label_1.width(), self.label_1.height())
        print('label_2 Size After Expanding: ', self.label_2.width(), self.label_2.height())
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need to know that?

Comment: I have two vertically cropped video windows.  I thought that forcing them to their full screen dimensions will keep them from resizing when hiding the other window and its horizontal and vertical sliders. Thanks for leading me to resizeEvent - I think this will work.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand: what do you mean by "two vertically cropped video windows"? And why should maximizing prevent resizing of the remaining widgets when one is hidden? I'm beginning to think that you were asking this question for the wrong reason.

Comment: I have two video windows stacked vertically, each has a horizontal slider (only during replay). I have two live video streams coming in. For each stream, I crop to the middle 50%, write it to a recorder, and display it. In replay mode, the window not being replayed disappears (hide()), but the window of the replay video changes dimensions, which I don't want. I've tried different size policies, masking, etc. The mainwindow will always be maximized. I think that if I change the QLabel size policies to Fixed after maximizing, then they will not change dimensions. This should be a simple solution

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your requirement: if the video widget is hidden, what is the expected result? Should the main window keep its maximized size, and just hide the video widget leaving an "empty" space on the window? Or do you want to resize the main window accordingly (so, making it vertically smaller)? In the first case, use [`setRetainSizeWhenHidden()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html#setRetainSizeWhenHidden). The second is a bit more complex: a maximized window cannot be resized, you have to make it normal again and manually update its geometry.

Comment: I want empty space and no resizing. When replay is done, the other window is displayed again and both video windows go back to live video. I didn't know about  setRetainSizePlicyWhenHidden().  That looks like it will also work and is probably a simpler solution. I only tried the size policies in QT Designer. I read some of the QSizePolicy documentation, but evidently not enough.  This has been great. Thanks.

Comment: Remember that Designer only provides basic support to properties of widgets. Advanced properties (like size policies or fonts) almost always provide more complex features than what Designer exposes, and those are often not available for 2 reasons: 1. due to the complexity/exclusivity of those features and limitations of the Designer framework, their behavior can be erratic or unexpected; 2. an attempt to avoid unnecessary extended configuration that could be easily achieved by code for special cases (like yours). The solution, though, is always the same: study the documentation :-)

Comment: @musicamante  I must have been doing something incorrect when implementing setRetainSizeWhenHidden() - I couldn't get it to work. I noticed that when the first time the QMainWindow is shown is with showMaximum(), the resizeEvent() is called twice - first time with the default geometry and the second time with the maximized geometry. My solution is to wait until the second time resizeEvent() is entered and then set the widgets to fixed width and height and then set the sizePolicy to Maximum for width and height. It's kind of klugey, but it works.

Comment: After moving the solution in my last comment from the minimalized script to my real script, the QLabel remained the size I wanted but it dropped one row in the GridLayout. Adding the setRetainSizeWhenHidden() after making the height and width fixed solved my issue.  The multiple solutions from @musicamante worked well.I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: About the first part of your next to last comment, that is expected, as explained in my answer (the last paragraph explicitly points out that behavior). Be aware, though, that yours are not completely reliable workarounds (I tried some of that myself in the past): in the long run you'll see that they only work on very specific cases, and some unexpected behavior will happen sooner or later. Besides, if you only want a placeholder, just place a temporary, empty/transparent widget, and switch it with the *actual* video widget whenever you need it. You can even use a QStackedWidget.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When widgets are created but not yet *mapped* ("shown") on the screen, they always have a default size:

- 100x30 for all widgets that have a parent *explicitly* set (either by adding the parent argument in the constructor, or by calling `setParent()`);
- 640x480 for all top level widgets (widgets that have no parent *explicitly* set);

The only exception is when size constraints exist, like in your case: the first label has a fixed height, and that's what is shown in the output (remember that "fixed size" means that *both* minimum and maximum sizes are the same).

Calling `show()` or `setVisible(True)` the first time, automatically creates (amongst others) a `Resize` event on the top level or parent widget, which automatically activates the layout for that widget and eventually recursively creates `Resize` events for all widgets managed by its layout, based on the layout computations. This does *not* happen before showing the widgets the first time.

This is done for optimization reasons: updating a layout can be very demanding, especially for complex UIs with multiple nested layouts that contain widgets that have different size hints, policies, stretches, etc.

Since geometries will be updated anyway as soon as the window will be shown, there's no point in setting a size until the full layout has been completed. Also note that using `setGeometry()` or `resize()` *prior* showing the widget the first time will *not* activate the layout, as explained above.

That said, it *is* possible to update sizes based on the current layout even if widgets have not been shown yet: you have to explicitly [`activate()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#activate) the layout manager. This is also normally achieved by calling the layout's `sizeHint()`, **after** it has been set on its widget.

But, be aware: in order to get the correct sizes based on the layout, you need to activate *all* layouts, up to the top level widget. QMainWindow has its own private layout, so you need to activate that too.
Since you've overwritten the default [`layout()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#layout) function with `self.layout`, the only way to access it is through the `super()` call.

Then, there's another problem: functions that change the window state (maximized, minimized, full screen and normal) do *not* directly resize the window. Those functions (including `setWindowState()`) actually "ask" the OS to change the window state, then the OS will decide on its own if the request is acceptable and eventually resize the window according to its behavior based on the requested state.
That resizing will happen at an **undefined** point after that call, and there's no direct way to know when: the OS might have some fancy animation to show the state change, and that might cause continuous changes in the size or even an abrupt change to the new size after that "process" has finished. Even using `processEvents()` won't be enough, since that function only processes events directly handled by Qt, and Qt cannot know anything about external OS events.

The only way to know for sure the size of widgets *after any resizing*, is by overriding the `resizeEvent()`.

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):  
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # ...
        super().layout().activate()
        self.layout.activate()
        
        print('label_1 Size Before Showing: ', self.label_1.size())
        print('label_2 Size Before Showing: ', self.label_2.size())
        self.showMaximized()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        print('label_1 Size After Showing/Resizing: ', self.label_1.size())
        print('label_2 Size After Showing/Resizing: ', self.label_2.size())
```

This will correctly print, before `showMaximized()`:

```
label_1 Size Before Expanding:  PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(388, 100)
label_2 Size Before Expanding:  PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(388, 182)
label_1 Size After Resizing:  PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(388, 100)
label_2 Size After Resizing:  PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(388, 182)
label_1 Size After Resizing:  PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(1428, 100)
label_2 Size After Resizing:  PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(1428, 757)
```

Note that the `resizeEvent` is called twice: the first one is right after any `show*()` call, the second is when the window has been actually maximized. If you remove the `activate` calls above, the first output will be the same as the default values explained at the beginning.

Comment: Wow - another wonderful explanation.  This makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 3):

To get the true size, I think you need to trigger off of resizeEvent. I don't know of a way to force the event loop to finish maximizing before you query the size. Even `app.processEvents()` seems to have no effect on this when you run it in __init__:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QSizePolicy, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):  
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)        
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 300)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        
        self.label_1 = QLabel(self)
        self.label_1.setStyleSheet('background-color: green')
        self.label_1.setFixedHeight(100)
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.label_1.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label_1)
        
        self.label_2 = QLabel(self)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet('background-color: red')
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.label_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.show()
        # ~ print('label_1 Size Before Expanding: ', self.label_1.width(), self.label_1.height())
        # ~ print('label_2 Size Before Expanding: ', self.label_2.width(), self.label_2.height())
        self.showMaximized()
        # ~ print('label_1 Size After Expanding: ', self.label_1.width(), self.label_1.height())
        # ~ print('label_2 Size After Expanding: ', self.label_2.width(), self.label_2.height())
        
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        print('label_1 Size : ', self.label_1.width(), self.label_1.height())
        print('label_2 Size : ', self.label_2.width(), self.label_2.height())
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    app.exec()
```

which gives

```
label_1 Size :  100 100
label_2 Size :  100 30
label_1 Size :  1268 100
label_2 Size :  1268 869
```

Comment: Wonderful!  Works perfectly!