# How to get the size hint of the extended widget in QGridLayout in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

How to determine the widget size in QGridLayout? In My example, I get the same size hint value of Button1, Button5 and Button4. But In QGridlayout, the widgets, we see,  are in different sizes. I need the size hint value of extended Widgets. How to get it?

```
 from PyQt5.QtWidgets import  *

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("QGridlayout")
        self.btn1 = QPushButton("Button_1")
        self.btn2 = QPushButton("Button_2")
        self.btn3 = QPushButton("Button_3")
        self.btn4 = QPushButton("Button_4")
        self.btn4.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum,QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
        self.btn5 = QPushButton("Button_5")
        self.btn6 = QPushButton("Button_6")
        self.btn7 = QPushButton("Button_7")
        self.btn8 = QPushButton("Button_8")
        self.btn9 = QPushButton("Button_9")
        # self.btn7.setFixedSize(200,200)

        self.gl = QGridLayout()
        self.gl.addWidget(self.btn1,0,0,1,1)
        self.gl.addWidget(self.btn2,0,1,1,1)
        self.gl.addWidget(self.btn3,0,2,1,1)
        self.gl.addWidget(self.btn4,0,3,3,1)
        self.gl.addWidget(self.btn5,1,0,1,2)
        self.gl.addWidget(self.btn6,2,0,1,3)
        self.gl.addWidget(self.btn7,3,0,1,4)
        self.gl.addWidget(self.btn8,1,2,1,1)
        self.gl.setRowStretch(4,1)
        self.gl.setColumnStretch(2,1)
        print("size hint of button 4 are :", self.btn4.sizeHint())
        print("size hint of button 1 are :", self.btn1.sizeHint())
        print("size hint of button 5 are :", self.btn5.sizeHint())
        self.setLayout(self.gl)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I believe you're confusing the size hint, the size policy and the *final* size of widgets. First of all, the size hint of the widget is *not* the actual size the widget will eventually have once shown, but it is **a hint** for that. Then, the size hint doesn't consider the size policy. In fact, the size policy tells *how* the size hint will be used to the layout manager. Finally, you can only get the actual size of a widget once its layout is activated, which normally happens as soon as the widget is shown the first time. Can you explain exactly why you need to know the size of those widgets?

Comment: Getting widget size is a little tricky. You don't get an accurate size from `__init__`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70764511/9705687) for some ideas. The easiest thing is to override `resizeEvent` and print the widget size there.

Comment: @musicamante.. want to insert a vertical line between two widgets. Fix vertical line height is 75% of the frame height. But frame height is same in all conditions

Comment: @Bala Then you asked the wrong question (see the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). As said above, you can't rely on the size of widgets until they're shown, if you want a widget that has always 75% the height of a parent, then override the `resizeEvent()` of the parent and set a fixed height for that widget.

Comment: @musicamante, if i got a solution code or idea, for this question, i will imement the same for my ptoblem.